# Running Selenium WebDriver tests with Firefox no longer works on Ubuntu

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Running Selenium (Webdriver) tests with Firefox locally on my Ubuntu workstation no longer works.

The exact same setup worked before, but I think Firefox was upgraded at some point (it's now 16.0.2 from the Ubuntu package `16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1`), after which it stopped working. In normal use Firefox works ok.

With Webdriver, when I run a testcase (via my IDE), **an empty Firefox window is opened, but the test does not start**. After 45 seconds, it times out with this error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous5012217980260937474webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on {2204c510-88f3-11db-b606-0800200c9a66} modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on yslow@yahoo-inc.com modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on {02450954-cdd9-410f-b1da-db804e18c671} modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on {c45c406e-ab73-11d8-be73-000a95be3b12} modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on {a6fd85ed-e919-4a43-a5af-8da18bda539f} modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on pythonformatters@seleniumhq.org modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on rubyformatters@seleniumhq.org modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on javaformatters@seleniumhq.org modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on csharpformatters@seleniumhq.org modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Add-on firebug@software.joehewitt.com modified in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Loading bootstrap scope from /tmp/anonymous5012217980260937474webdriver-profile/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi
*** LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method install on firebug@software.joehewitt.com version 1.10.6
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method startup on firebug@software.joehewitt.com version 1.10.6
*** LOG ubufox.urn: Starting
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous5012217980260937474webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
*** LOG addons.xpi: Loading bootstrap scope from /tmp/anonymous5012217980260937474webdriver-profile/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi
*** LOG addons.xpi: Calling bootstrap method startup on firebug@software.joehewitt.com version 1.10.6
*** LOG ubufox.urn: Starting

Build info: version: '2.23.1', revision: '17143', time: '2012-06-08 18:59:28'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-16-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_26'

Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:151)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:93)
at fi.company.product.testing.selenium.AbstractSeleniumTest.getFirefoxDriver(AbstractSeleniumTest.java:99)
at fi.company.product.testing.selenium.AbstractSeleniumTest.setup(AbstractSeleniumTest.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at fi.company.product.testing.selenium.ScreenshotTestRule$1.evaluate(ScreenshotTestRule.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

In our base test class, the `FirefoxDriver` is initialised simply like this:

```
new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxProfile())
```

...although I also tried pointing to an existing Firefox profile dir (something like `/home/jonik/.mozilla/firefox/vds3ono5.default`) with the same result.

**Any ideas how to get the tests running again?**

- Selenium (Webdriver) 2.23.1
- Firefox 16.0.2
- Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: If some essential info is missing from the question, please point it out! (Also feel free to migrate to another SE site it this fits better somewhere else.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox 16 isn't supported in v2.23. You will have to either upgrade to v2.26, or downgrade Firefox.

Comment: One thing of note though: at [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/download/), the latest version available is 2.25; no mention of 2.26! But I found 2.26 at [Selenium's Google Code downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).